# Flutter Compress image freeze web browser

Tags: flutter, dart

How do you compress image on web browser ?
I Used `image_compression: ^1.0.4` .

```
  static Future<Uint8List> flutterImageToUint8List(Image image) async {
    developer.log("Convert Image to bytes");
    final completer = Completer<ui.Image>();
    image.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
      ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
        completer.complete(info.image);
      }),
    );

    return completer.future
        .then((value) => value.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png))
        .then((value) => compressImage(value!.buffer.asUint8List()))
        .then((value) => value.rawBytes);
  }

  static Future<ImageFile> compressImage(Uint8List bytes) async {
    developer.log("Compress image size: ${bytes.length}");
    var imageFile = ImageFile(filePath: "_compressed_", rawBytes: bytes);
    Configuration config = Configuration(
        pngCompression: PngCompression.defaultCompression,
        jpgQuality: 40,
        outputType: OutputType.jpg
    );

    var imageFileConfiguration = ImageFileConfiguration(input: imageFile,config: config);
    return compute(compressInQueue,imageFileConfiguration);
  }
```

according to [document](https://pub.dev/packages/image_compression) :
`compressInQueue` is async method .
but web browser freezed .
Also i wrap this method with compute . but still web browser freezing .
I can not understand how can fix this problem !

```
Flutter 3.13.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ead455963c (9 days ago) • 2023-09-26 18:28:17 -0700
Engine • revision a794cf2681
Tools • Dart 3.1.3 • DevTools 2.25.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing `async` and `concurrency`. `async` uses same thread, so that's why you get freeze. `compute` is the right way, but, sadly, not for flutter web. read [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33577)